# De Rham's cohomology groups by definition

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I have to find the De Rham's cohomology groups of $X$, where:

**a)**$X=S^1\times S^1$.
**b)** $X=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \mathbb{R}$.
**c)** $X=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$.

**(d)** $X=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus (L_1\cup C)$,  $L_1=\{x=y=0\}$ and $C=\{x^2+y^2=1,z=0\}$.

**(e)** $X=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus (L_2\cup C)$,  $L_2=\{x=3,y=0\}$ and $C=\{x^2+y^2=1,z=0\}$.

I've seen for **(a)** using Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I would like to do it by definition. I have no idea.

For **(b)** I will identify $\mathbb{R}=\{(x,0,0)\}$, and then take $U=\{(x,y,z)/yz>0\}$ and $V=\{(x,y,z)/yz<0\}$, then

$$U\cup V=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \mathbb{R},\quad U\cap V=\emptyset$$ and then use Mayer-Vietoris.

For **(c)** $S^1=C\cap \mathbb{R}^2$, where $C=\{(x,y,z)/x^2+y^2=1\}$ the cilynder and $\mathbb{R}^2=\{(x,y,0)\}$. Then

$$\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \left(C\cap \mathbb{R}^2\right) =\left(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C\right)\cup\left(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \mathbb{R}^2\right)=U\cup V$$
and then use Mayer-Vietoris.

Are my ideas for **(b)** and **(c)** right? Can they be solved by definition?

For the other ones, i can use properties ou M-V sequence. Here is what I tried
**(d)** $X=\left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus L_1\right)\cap \left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus C\right)=M\cap N$, but $M$ and $N$ are like **(b)** and **(c)**.

**(e)** Thinking...

I will appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Frankly speaking, Mayer-Vietoris sequence is precisely the instrument which allows you to find representatives for homology classes in closed forms. Only example of noncontractible manifold where I can compute cohomology of de Rham complex explicitly with reasonable effort is $S^1$, and even then  I see no reason to do that.

Comment: @xsnl Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me if my approach is right? Specially for (d) and give me a hint for (e).

Comment: Regarding (d) and (e): MV sequence allows you to compute cohomology of $U \cap V$ if you know cohomology of union. Couldn't say anything meaningful about your approach, because the choice of two open subsets is pretty obvious (well, some choices make geometric picture more clear, but whatever), whereas computing maps in MV sequence is not.